# 3 dice thrown together

Tags: combinations

If $3$ dice are thrown together the no. of ways in which the sum of numbers appearing on the dice is $n$, is?   $ \ $ $9 \leq n  \leq14$

My try:
$(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^3$

The sum of the  coefficients of 
$x^9$ to $x^{14}$ should be found.
But I am getting stuck up in calculations. Now I have started doubting this method.

Comment: Clarifying your question... You seek the total number of ways to roll three dice and get sums of 9 through 14, inclusive. Correct?

Comment: Yes,you got it right.

Comment: Your approach should work. Please show your efforts.